# Bazel is building executables without .exe extension

Tags: windows, bazel

I have somehow misconfigured Bazel on Windows 10 so that it's producing executables without the .exe extension. Instead of producing binaries like `hello.exe` it will produce a binary called `hello`.

For example, I have a target

```
# examples/BUILD

cc_binary(
    name = "gflags_example",
    srcs = ["gflags_example.cpp"],
    deps = [
        "@com_github_gflags_gflags//:gflags"
    ]
)
```

and then I run `bazel build -s examples:gflags_example` and found that it's calling `link.exe` like so

```
 C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.24.28314/bin/HostX64/x64/link.exe @bazel-out/x64_windows-fastbuild/bin/examples/gflags_example-2.params
```

And in the `glfags_example-2.params` file it's specifying, among other things, `/OUT:bazel-out/x64_windows-dbg/bin/examples/gflags_example` where I guess it should say `/OUT:bazel-out/x64_windows-dbg/bin/examples/gflags_example.exe`

How can I influence Bazel to produce the correct `gflags_example-2.params` file so I can get my `.exe` extensions back?

Answer (score 0):

I think that's normal. Did it work before?

You just need to build `bazel build //examples:gflags_example.exe`

Comment: Yes, it used to produce the `.exe` extension automatically

Comment: I used to navigate to the `.exe`s so that I could open them in the Visual Studio debugger. Now Visual Studio does not recognize them as executables and I have to rename them first.

Comment: Could be a regression. Did you update the source tree? Did you update Bazel, or do you use Bazelisk (which uses the latest Bazel by default)?

Comment: I did update bazel from 0.29.1 to 2.2.0. I'm also using the crosstool for nvcc from the Tensorflow project. I'm not sure if that crosstool generates the `.params` file though. To be honest I blindly copied and pasted until my cuda code started to compile correctly.